# R: Make plot axis as in histogram

Tags: r, plot, histogram, axis

I want the y axis in regular `plot()` function to start at the bottom of the plot area similar to `hist()` function. In other words I would like to have zeros of both axis at the same level. Here is my working example

```
set.seed(1)
data <- data.frame(
  type = as.factor(sample(c('A', 'B', 'C'), size = 100, replace = T)),
  value = rexp(100, 1/3)
)
plot(data$type)
par(new=TRUE)
plot(tapply(data$value, data$type, mean), 
     xaxt="n", yaxt="n", xlab="", ylab="", 
     xlim=c(0.55,3.45), ylim=c(0, 5), bty='n', pch=24, bg='black')
axis(4)
```

I tried to use parameter `yaxs = 'i'` in the `plot()` function, but it moved the axis too low. Is there any solution to this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Find one variant

set `ylim` in first plot

try

```
plot(data$type, yaxs = 'i',ylim=c(0,max(apply(data, 2, table)[[1]])))
par(new=TRUE)
plot(tapply(data$value, data$type, mean), 
     xaxt="n", yaxt="n", xlab="", ylab="", 
     xlim=c(0.55,3.45), ylim=c(0, 5), bty='n', pch=24, bg='black',yaxs = 'i')
axis(4)
axis(1,at=c(0,5)) #only for show that one lvl
```